# Gnus: get rid of ~/Mail and ~/News folders

Tags: emacs, email-client, gnus

[Gnus](http://gnus.org/) (Emacs's mail client) creates directories `~/Mail/` and `~/News`. I don't want to clutter my home folder, how can i change this directories to, say, `~/.emacs.d/mail/` and `~/.emacs.d/news/`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First i executed `apropos-value ~/Mail/`. It threw me many variables, that contain this string in their values. On my Debian i installed package `emacs24-el` so i could track down these variables in code. I ran `describe-variable` on the variable `nnfolder-directory`, which value was `~/Mail/`. In went to the code and found out it's initialized like this:

```
(defvoo nnfolder-directory (expand-file-name message-directory))
```

The same was with the varible `nndraft-directory` that contained value `~/News/`, which actually came from variable `gnus-directory`. For some reason the directory `~/Mail/archive/` is still created, i think `nnfolder-directory` is initialized before i set `message-directory` in init file.

**Resume:** to change your mail and news directories, put this into [init file](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile):

```
(setq message-directory "~/.emacs.d/mail/")
(setq gnus-directory "~/.emacs.d/news/")
(setq nnfolder-directory "~/.emacs.d/mail/archive")
```

Comment: What about the drafts directory and the sent directory?

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `apropos-value` – I had no idea one could do that!

Answer (score 3):

I've traced the problem sindikat observed (that for some reason the directory `~/Mail/archive/` is still created). At first I thought there was indeed a bug in gnus initialization code which I've reported here:

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18284

But then I realized that the `message-directory` setting was being overriden by a previous definition in my newsrc file. So you will have to edit your newsrc and remove the offending definition in order to remove every trace of the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution works for most of those variables, I couldn't set the draft directory `nndraft-directory` since it's overridden when calling `gnus` (that's the only exception). That's mostly because `nndraft` is considered a backend and is therefore configured from the `nnoo-state-alist` list. Sadly, `nnoo-state-alist` is configured at loading and takes the initial `nndraft-directory` value.

A quick and dirty fix would be to change the list value:

```
(setq nndraft-directory "~/.emacs.d/mail/drafts/")
(setcdr (assoc 'nndraft-directory
               (nnoo-variables 'nndraft))
        nndraft-directory)
```